# store whole http session in cookies to provide high-availability

Tags: java, session, tomcat, session-cookies, high-availability

I want to store whole http session in client cookie to provide high-availability in many tomcat servers.
But in tomcat I did not find how to do this.
Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: Do you mean the whole session is stored in the cookie (i.e. in the user's browser and not on the server) or something else?

Comment: You'd better not use the session at all.